# Windows computers can only print test pages to shared Ubuntu printer

Tags: windows, printing, sharing

I have an HP printer connected to my Ubuntu 11.10 machine. I have 2 other Windows computers (Win7/Vista). Both of these Windows computers can view, install, and print a test page to the shared Ubuntu printer. The Windows computers cannot print anything to the Ubuntu printer except the test page under properties or during install. I have tried word and pdf files.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem? I have the exact same one with a similar setup.

Comment: @waldrumpus RmburaK's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/140754/929) solved this for me

Comment: @waldrumpus Indeed, I had exactly the same issue, sharing over cups instead of samba fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

In Linux stop sharing the printer through Samba.

Share it through CUPS instead: go to http://localhost:631/ and there will be spoe "Share printers" checkbox.

On Windows add a Network printer, and don't search for it; add manually this address:

http://servername_or_IP:631/printers/printer_name

printer_name is the name shown in the CUPS Web interface for your printer.

You will be prompted to choose the proper model and a driver will be installed. That's it.

Unlike Samba, advanced feature also work now.

Comment: I'd vote +10 if I could.
EASY and PERFECT solution.
Thanks a ton :)

Comment: I had issues printing PDF pages and some excel sheets. Thanks a lot for this! :)

Comment: Found this after over an hour trying to get it to work not realizing I was doing it through samba rather than CUPS... thanks for the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

In the print dialog go to:
Preferences->Document Options->Advanced Printing Settings-> select "DISABLED" (a drop-box)

It's a HP driver on Microsoft thing.

I have the F2280 (HP Deskjet F2200 Series). Had to disable 2-up printing on an 8-page PDF.

Answer (score 1):

If he's already printed a test page you can bet samba is already installed. What you may want to play around with is the encoding/protocol. I think you may have to send print jobs in RAW format, or try one of the other formats it offers. I'm pretty sure that is where your problem will lay.

Comment: So, how do send print jobs in RAW format? How do I try that?

Answer (score -1):

#### This is a Ubuntu Guide For Windows Users: Connecting To Shared Printers On Windows Computers.

http://www.watchingthenet.com/connecting-to-shared-printers-on-windows-computers.html